# CGrect NSArray error

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsarray, cgrect

I'm trying to create a CGRect array from a `Swift` class, that eventually will be send to an `Objective C` class.

As far as i understand, `Objective C` expecting a `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` when creating a `CGRect` array. I tried to make an `NSArray` and appending `CGRect`, tho it print the error :

```
 Cannot convert value of type 'NSValue' to expected argument type 'NSArray'
```

Swift Code:

```
            var rects = [NSArray]()
            let v = NSValue(CGRect: feature.bounds)
            rects.append(v)
```

Any suggestions folks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an `NSArray`:

```
var rects = [NSArray]()
```

This is a Swift array of `NSArray` objects (i.e an array within an array). If you want to append `NSValues` to your array, then you want a `[NSValue]`.

```
var rects = [NSValue]()
let v = NSValue(CGRect: feature.bounds)
rects.append(v)
```

However, I would generally advise against doing this (depends on your exact use case) as it adds a wrapper that Swift itself doesn't need, as well as reducing type safety. If you need to interact with this array in Swift before sending it off to an Objective-C API, then I would instead create an array of `CGRects` directly, as [@Bhushan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37456848/2976878).

```
var rects = [CGRect]()
rects.append(CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
```

However, you now can't pass this array to an `NSArray` argument, you'll get an error saying `Cannot convert value of type '[CGRect]' to '[AnyObject]'`. In order to deal with this, you can simply use `map` on your array – in order to wrap each `CGRect` in an `NSValue` before sending it off to Objective-C.

```
someObjCInstance.someProperty = rects.map{NSValue(CGRect:$0)}
```

This way you can have the best of both worlds. You get the flexibility and type safety of being able to use an array of `CGRects` in Swift and you also get the interoperability with Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to create `CGRect` array in swift you can write like this :

```
var rectList = [CGRect]()

let rect1 = CGRectZero
rectList.append(rect1)
```

In your case you are creating array of array. That is why its saying "Cannot convert value of type 'NSValue' to expected argument type 'NSArray'"